# Order RSS content by an advanced custom field value

Tags: custom-field, query, advanced-custom-fields, order, rss

I have created a custom post-type called "event".

For this custom post-type I created an advanced custom field called "event_date".

Now I am trying to display the list of my events in a RSS feed.

I figured out how to display custom fields and featured image in my RSS feed but I cant figure out how to re-arrange the feed content according to the event_date and not the date when the post was created...

Can someone help me with a URL string query for RSS feed or a simple line I can add to my functions.php?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

hope this code will helpful for you

```
    $args = array(
  'post_type'         =>'event',
  'post_status'       => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'    => -1,
  'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
  'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'             => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am a designer not a coder and whereas I do see how helpful this code is I have no idea where to put it and how to query it.. Do I put it into functions.php? And then what to write in rss url string? This is how RSS feed looks like right now http://grid.tokyo.jp/feed/?post_type=event

Comment: you can put it in inside a template where the event post want to display

Comment: In this template you can load your rss wp_query ----------//code----------     function create_my_customfeed() {
load_template( TEMPLATEPATH . 'your-custom-feed.php'); // You'll create a your-custom-feed.php file in your theme's directory
}
add_action('do_feed_customfeed', 'create_my_customfeed', 10, 1);           refered link https://katz.co/648/